# How to make a sublist in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

How would I do this in prolog?

I have already got this to make a sublist, but now need to make sure the first and last element of the second list are not included in the first list.

```
sublist(S,L):- append(_,L2,L), append(S,_,L2).
```

Comment: Please include both the actual question and your code in the question. Not as images but as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching such that the head and the tail are non-empty:

```
sublist(S,L) :-
    append([_|_],L2,L),
    append(S,[_|_],L2).
```

In the first `append/3` we thus ensure that the part before the sublist is non-empty, and in the second `append/3` we ensure that the part after the sublist is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:-

```
    sub([],[]).
    sub(S,A):- 
        append(_L1,L2,A),
        append(S1,_L3,L2),
        removefirstelement(S1,S2),
        removelastelement(S,S2).
    
    removefirstelement([_|T],T).
    removelastelement([],[_]).
    removelastelement([X|Xs], [X,Next|T]) :- 
        removelastelement(Xs, [Next|T]).

?-sub(S,[a,b,c,d,e]).
S = []
S = [b]
S = [b, c]
S = [b, c, d]
S = []
S = [c]
S = [c, d]
S = []
S = [d]
S = []
```

Just add the removefirstelement and removelastelement predicates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand the removefirstelement function, but could you maybe elaborate a bit on what the removelastelement function does? I am very new to this language.

Comment: @leximus So, removelastelement takes two arguments meaning S and S2, S2 which is coming from remove first element. Here S is empty right now. When we give removelastelement these values S becomes [X|Xs] and S2 becomes [X,Next|T]. Note when we write [H|T] it means a head value and T the remaining list, so X is the head value, Next is the next number to X and T is the tail. Similarly Xs is also a Tail. So [X,Next|T] is the list we get after removing the first element. Now with this list we are updating it with [Next|Tail] and giving the values to Xs which will update the result of S.